# Slow cypher queries in Neo4j server mode - jersey-REST

Tags: java, rest, neo4j, jersey, cypher

I am accessing and querying a graph db via REST, with Jersey and I am obtaining Json files with the results, but it is slower than querying it via embedded. My graph has 350.000 nodes and 1.500.000 relationships. I don't know if there is a way for not blocking the db when it is accessed by a user via embedded... thanks

- DOMAIN MODEL: 
  300.000 nodes, 1.500.000 relationships (of 40 types, including IS_A type). There is about 15 big hierarchies (each of one has between 1.000 and 100.000 nodes), and these hierarchies (its nodes) are related with the nodes of other hierarchies.
- QUERY:

`MATCH (a: Concept{conceptid : '123456'}) <- [:RELCL] - (b: Concept)  - [:REL {reltype: '112233'}] -> (c: Concept)  - [:RELCL] -> (av: Concept {conceptid: '654321'}) 
RETURN DISTINCT b.conceptid AS CONCEPTID`

Note that `RELCL` is the IS_A relationship.

Note that

```
MATCH (a: Concept{conceptid : '123456'}) <- [:RELCL] - (b: Concept)
```

b returns 300.000 nodes.

Note that

```
(c: Concept)  - [:RELCL] -> (av: Concept {conceptid: '654321'})
```

c returns 300.000 nodes.

Time executed via (Neo4j embedded):

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(query));
```

= 12 s.

Time executed via (Neo4j server mode (Neo4j Community 2.1.5) - jersey-REST):

```
final String txUri = SERVER_ROOT_URI + "transaction/commit";        
WebResource resourceQuery = Client.create().resource( txUri );
String payload = "{\"statements\" : [ {\"statement\" : \"" +query + "\"} ]}";
 ClientResponse responseQuery= resourceQuery
.accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
.type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
.entity( payload )
.post( ClientResponse.class );

String res = String.format("POST [%s] to\n [%s], \nstatus code [%d %s], returned data: "+ System.getProperty( "file.separator" ) + "%s\n",
payload, txUri, responseQuery.getStatus(),
responseQuery.getClientResponseStatus(), responseQuery.getEntity( String.class ) );
```

= 240 s.

When executing both codes in Eclipse, I put in *Run Configuration* **-Xms12G
-Xmx16G** as *VM Arguments.* I see, when executing embedded version, that RAM increase over 8GB in javaw process. But when executing Server-REST version, it only reach 130MB. (The PC where I am executing the codes has 16GB of RAM).

In *Neo4j GUI settings*, *Database Configuration, Server Configuration and Java VM Options* files, has the default values.

Thank you again.

Comment: Can you provide way more details: your domain model, your queries, your code, your server and client config, network setup? etc? Without more information no one will be able to answer your question.

Comment: Are you including the time taken to marshall to json in the non-embedded example?

Comment: The time counter starts exactly at the beginning of the code block, and stops exactly at the end of the code block, just after the execution of the "String res = ..." statement.